# Wordpress jQuery validate.js not putting error messages into error labels

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I use jquery.validate.js plugin to client-side validate forms - validation works fine - it highlights (adds classes) correctly, it even puts labels after each empty required field - but here comes the problem - it does not put any error messages into the labels.

How to make validation plugin to add the error messages inside the label tag?

I use default - no settings :

```
  myForm = $("#myForm_id").validate();
```

**SOLUTION:** below as an answer :)

Comment: [By default, the messages will show](http://jsfiddle.net/4X7h6/).  And no settings is fine, but then tell us how you're defining your validation rules.  You'll have to show _more complete_ code including your HTML markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**By default, the messages WILL show.**

So *especially if youre using wordpress* and there is no javascript error - there is like 90% chance that your app is in *conflict with some other app* (plugin/theme), which could redefine the messages or completely clear them.

**To fix this look for lines similar to this:**

```
jQuery.validator.messages.required = ""; 
// or just: 
jQuery.validator.messages = "";
```

Remember that $ = jQuery so it can also start with $ instead.